How to manage memory consumption in deep learning models?
When I run this code, the runtime session automatically closes. There is no space in RAM left. Hence the session closes automatically. I am using pytorch in Google Colab notebook. I tried switching from CPU to GPU but still the session closes automatically.
!pip install datasets
!pip install transformers

import torch
import wandb
import torch.nn as nn
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer, DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoConfig

!huggingface-cli login

model_name = "distilgpt2"

print(f"Using GPU: {torch.cuda.is_available()}")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

len(tokenizer)

tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

len(tokenizer)

class Custom_GPT2_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer):
        super().__init__()

        self.gpt2 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

        self.gpt2.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

        for param in self.gpt2.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

        self.gpt2.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

        self.custom_layer = nn.Linear(self.gpt2.config.vocab_size, self.gpt2.config.vocab_size)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, labels=None):

        outputs = self.gpt2(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

        logits = self.custom_layer(outputs.logits)

        loss = None
        if labels is not None:
            loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            # loss = loss_func(logits, labels)
            loss = loss_func(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), labels.view(-1))

        return {
            'loss': loss,
            'logits': logits
        }

model = Custom_GPT2_Model(tokenizer)

# Data Pre-Processing

dataset = load_dataset("wikitext", "wikitext-2-raw-v1")

dataset

def tokenize_func(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples['text'], padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors='pt')

tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(tokenize_func, batched=True, remove_columns=['text'])
tokenized_dataset

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=0.5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
    fp16=True,
    warmup_steps=2500,
    learning_rate=0.1,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=5000,
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model = model,
    args = training_args,
    train_dataset = tokenized_dataset['train'].select(range(100)),
    eval_dataset = tokenized_dataset['test'].select(range(100)),
    data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)
)

trainer.train()

How should I manage memory while fine-tuning deep learning models?

Sometimes a model is just too big for the hardware you have.
